# Слово "сквалыга"

Tags: этимология, лексика, значение-слов, семантика

Интересует происхождение слова "сквалыга". Даже не могу предположить, от какого слова оно может происходить.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не только Вы не можете. Этимология темная.

сквалыга
сквалы́га диал. скавалы́га "скряга, попрошайка", новгор., тамб., тоб. (Даль), олонецк. (Кулик.), в последнем указано также скалы́га. Древнейшая форма, а также этимология неясны. Корш (у Преобр. II, 295) пытается возвести эти слова к русск. арготич. *склавы́га "раб, слуга", которое происходит, возм., из греч. σκλάβος "слуга". Маценауэр (LF 20, 7) предполагает существование приставки ска- и родство с вали́ть. Ильинский (РФВ 78, 200) сравнивает с лат. quisquiliae "отбросы, отребье рода человеческого", др.-инд. dantaskavanam "ковыряние в зубах". Все это сомнительно. Ср. скалы́га : ско́лить (см.). •• [Сквалы́га так относится к ска́лить, как гваздать : гад (в смысле вокализма). Сюда же скули́ть, чему соответствует и знач. слова. – Т.]

Этимологический словарь русского языка. — М.: Прогресс. М. Р. Фасмер. 1964—1973.

Answer (score 0):

Все очень просто: сквалыгой в допетровской Руси называли ручной инструмент для окоривания бревен (снятия с них коры, мелких сучков и неровностей - перед более технологичной обработкой). Представлял собой обычно металлическую полоску с зазубринами, с деревянной ручкой или с двумя (под обе руки). Сквалыжить - обдирать дочиста. Из сферы деревообработки термин перешел в общий вокабуляр в переносном значении - вроде "обдирать как липку", обчистить. Аналогия современного значения с процессом первичной деревообработки весьма прозрачная. Слово "сквалыжить" в смысле деревообработки еще можно встретить в сельской глубинке лесных регионов типа Перми и Кировской области. При Петре I на смену сквалыге пришел шерхебель. Вместе с тем в моем детстве (а это начало 1970-х) в хозяйственных магазинах встречался инструмент, очень похожий на сквалыгу и в том же назначении: стальной просечной лист был вырезан полоской, загнут по дуге и надет на такой же полукруглый держатель, на обоих концах - по ручке из какой-то древней фенол-формальдегидной пластмассы. Если не ошибаюсь, инструмент назывался "рубанок грубой обработки" или что-то вроде этого. Когда я впервые узнал про сквалыгу и увидел ее, то сразу же соотнес виденный в детстве инструмент с этим словом и назначением.